# T-SQL query to select values with closer timestamp

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to make a query that based on an ID from table A to display the closest row from table P that has the same TimestampLocal column ad table A.

What I've managed to do:

```
 IF(A.Generated - P.Local) >= 0 THEN
       select P.Location where P.Local = A.Generated + MIN(A.Generated - P.Local)
    ELSE
       select P.Location where P.Local = A.Generated + MAX(A.Generated - P.Local)
```

I'm trying to get the Value from table P.

```
IF (select datediff(second, a.Generated,p.Local) from A a inner join P p on a.VId=p.VId where a.Id = 830566) >=0
select Location from P where Local = dateadd(millisecond,(select Min(datediff(second, a.Generated,p.Local)) from A a inner join P p on a.VId=p.VId where a.Id=830566), 
(select Generated from A where Id=830566))

ELSE

select Location from P where Local =dateadd(second,(select Max(datediff(millisecond, a.Generated,p.Local)) from A a inner join P p on a.VId=p.VId where a.Id=830566), 
(select Generated from A where Id=830566))
```

But I got the error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

and

> The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.

But I don't know why :( It is possible to get just the closest row from table P based on table A Id? And if there are more than one rows from P with the same TimeStampLocal to get just the first one?

**UPDATE**

Table A:

```
Id       Generated                            VId
830566 | 2017-06-04 10:38:22.2000000 -07:00 | 5635
830567 | 2017-06-04 10:38:45.1000000 -07:00 | 5634
830568 | 2017-06-04 10:31:59.6000000 -07:00 | 5638
```

Table P:

```
VId    Local                                Location
5638 | 2017-06-04 10:26:17.9000000 -07:00 | 0xE6
5638 | 2017-06-04 10:31:48.6000000 -07:00 | 0X7F
5638 | 2017-06-04 10:32:48.7000000 -07:00 | 0x3C
5634 | 2017-06-04 10:31:48.6000000 -07:00 | 0xA6
```

As example: For Id `830568` from Table A (received as a parameter) - VId `5638`, I should get the closest row from table P with the closest Local time and same VId, in this case the second one `2017-06-04 10:31:48.6000000 -07:00`, and for this row from P I'll need to get the Location: `0X7F`

Comment: can you post some sample data (as insert into...) and expected value (as text)?

Comment: @etsa I've made the necessary update

Comment: closest without going over or closest period? what if there was a 10:32:00 for VId 5638 should it be returned or still the value you stated?

Comment: If there was 10:32:00 for VId 5438 instead 10:31:59 it should return 10:32:00 because that's the closest time to the one from table A. The closest hour mustn't be the exact hour and minute to the start one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. If you want the closest time without "going over" then remove the `ABS()` around the `datediff()` function and uncomment out the join condition.

```
declare @TableA table (Id int, [Generated] datetime2, VId int)

declare @TableB table (VId int, [Local] datetime2, [Location] varchar(64))

insert into @TableA
values
(830566,'2017-06-04 10:38:22.2000000 -07:00',5635),
(830567,'2017-06-04 10:38:45.1000000 -07:00',5634),
(830568,'2017-06-04 10:31:59.6000000 -07:00 ',5638)

insert into @TableB values

(5638,'2017-06-04 10:26:17.9000000 -07:00','0xE6'),
(5638,'2017-06-04 10:31:48.6000000 -07:00','0X7F'),
(5638,'2017-06-04 10:32:48.7000000 -07:00','0x3C'),
(5634,'2017-06-04 10:31:48.6000000 -07:00','0xA6')


;with cte as(
select
    a.Id
    ,a.VId
    ,a.Generated
    ,b.Local
    ,b.Location
    ,ABS(DATEDIFF(second,a.Generated,b.Local)) as TD
from 
    @TableA a
inner join 
    @TableB b on
    b.VId = a.VId)
    --and b.local < a.Generated

select
    c.Id
    ,c.VId
    ,c.Location
from 
    cte c
    inner join
        (select ID, min(TD) TD
         from cte
         group by ID) c2 on c2.Id = c.Id and c2.TD = c.TD
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks a lot for your answer! :) Up!

Comment: You too! :)Thanks again!

Comment: may want to change second to millisecond if that accuracy level comes into play. just a thought.